# How to change mix config to vue.config.js

Tags: laravel, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli-3

I have a webpack config using laravel with vue, I am transforming it to vue spa app using vue-cli-3. But I am not able to understand how I can change mix config to vue.config.js.
This is my webpack.mix.js config.

```
resolve: {
    modules: [
        'node_modules',
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/assets/js'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/assets/svg')
      ]
  }
```

I want to resolve this in vue.config.js. How can I do it? Any recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code snippet you have is just a partial webpack configuration.

The `vue-cli` also accepts applying an arbitrary partial to its own underlying configuration, using the `vue.config.js` and its `configureWebpack` property ([docs here](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#configurewebpack)):

So you would do something like this:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      modules: [
        'node_modules',
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/assets/js'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/assets/svg')
      ]
    }
  }
}
```